# Getting an error in TFS Build Template which is using a custom build assembly "Activity could not be loaded..." How can I troubleshoot this?

Tags: tfsbuild

I downloaded the custom build Assembly from http://versionedtfsbuild.codeplex.com/.
I'm having major difficulty in getting errors resolved in the xaml in activities between Get Workspace and Update Buildnumber.
I've got the custom assemblies in a folder under my build templates folder and have my build controller pointing to that folder.
I've refreshed and restarted my build controller and have gone as far as recompiling the custom assembly source code. Still the errors persist.
There is also a red dot to the right of the assembly in the import section. 
I can successfully do a build but there are no errors in the build log.

Can someone tell me how to get this working?  I'm very new to TFSBuild and evaluating it to see if this is something we can used to help our build process. So far I can't get any custom assemblies to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied answer from comment:
You shouldn't have to do this but once I did and it fixed my issue. I copied the DLL to this folder on my machine. The build server was fine. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies. This is part of the search path.

Have you created a project the contains your build template XAML and reference to the custom build assembly?

Here is a great resource for learning about build customization with TFS 2010.
http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-1-Introduction.aspx

This part sounds like it relates to what you are trying to do.
http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/13/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-5-Increase-AssemblyVersion.aspx

I hope this helps.  TFSBuild is very customizable and should be able to meet your build process needs.  I have used it to automate many types of builds and deployments.

Comment: I read through those several times. I didn't see anywhere stating that a reference to the xaml template and a reference to the custom build assembly needed to be added to the project I'm building. I don't know.. Maybe I'm still missing something.

Comment: Can the xaml and the custom assembly be added to the solution. I have a lot of projects in my solution that I'm trying to build.

Comment: Did you download Ewald's buildprocess.zip sample? In there he has the solution set up with the activity project being referenced by the template project.  Try starting with something simple like his examples and see if you can get that to work. This should be a separate solution than what you are trying to build.  The solution with the custom activity and template could be shared across all of the solutions you are building.

Comment: Not at the moment. I've been focused on trying to get the issue fixed that I mentioned above. I downloaded the source code for the custom assembly I'm working with, signed, recompiled, added the custom assembly to the version control path as well as the GAC, then closed VS2010, then restarted my TFS Build Server... reopened VS2010 and when I open my XAML code I still get an error now of "Namespace "CustomBuildAssembly" cannot be resolved". I'm not seeing any other errors related to this.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do this but once I did and it fixed my issue.  I copyed the DLL to this folder on my machine.  The build server was fine.  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies.  This is part of the search path.

Comment: That appears to have fixed the issue I was having.  Thanks Mike!  :)

Comment: Great, glad it fixed it.  I copied the fix to the answer.